Rights to turn on/off the air conditioning or open windows in Shull
I once learnt that there was a halacha mentioned in Shulchan Aruch on who has the rights to open the window in a shull based on the proximity to the windows. If some people do not want the air conditioning on/window open and others do want this, who has the preference in halacha (obviously avoiding a machlokes)?

Welcome to MiYodeya Zwi Yosef and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
